# Do Indian documents need to be endorsed by the Ministry of External Affairs when applying for a UK Visitor Visa?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for UK standard visa from India to meet my husband living in the UK.

I already have my passport with my husband's name endorsed. The VFS agency has asked for my marriage certificate. Should I submit the marriage certificate attested by Ministry of External Affairs or just the certificate without attestation is enough?

Answer (score 7):

All documents you submit should be:

1. Translated into English (if not already in English). The translation should be done by an office authorized for such translations.
2. The documents should be endorsed by the issuing agency, and then further by the Ministry of External Affairs if its a government issued document (like a degree, a marriage certificate, property titles, etc.)
3. Bank statements do not need external endorsements, but rather should be on official bank letterhead and property notarized/signed. If they are not in English, they should be translated and both the original and translated copy be provided.

Source: many, many, many dealings in this area.